# Stored procedure query import from sql file into Oracle DB using command

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have one SQL file, which containing TWO stored procedure creation query.
When i tried to import the procedure into DB get some issues.

Case 1: Copy the entire content from SQL file into the worksheet in SQLDeveloper tool. and press F5.
Executed correctly and 2 stored procedure created.

Case 2: SQL file path specified in worksheet and press F5.
Executed correctly and 2 stored procedure created.

[image]

Case 3: **ISSUE**
Tried to import the query using batch Command using below code.

```
> sqlplus -s -l userName/Password@xe @%filename%
```

Only First defined Procedure in the SQL file is created.

[image]

Is there any syntax to follow if we are importing query using batch command?

Also tried by removing the 1st Stored procedure code. But still same. Not created in DB and no error returned in the cmd, screen just waiting.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can we see the content (may be not actual but sudo code) , you may need to add '/' at end of first procedure.

Comment: I'd rather say *at the end of the **second** procedure*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "/" at the end of each Procedure solved the problem